# jQuery plugin custom event trigger not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-plugins, dom-events

It's been a while since I've done a jQuery plugin and I'm working off a pretty common boilerplate with options and internal events. In one of the internal methods I need to trigger a custom event so that other pages can capture the event and work with it. More specifically in this usage, at the end of drawing on a `canvas` element I want to be able to capture the event outside of the plugin in order to grab the `canvas` content for sending elsewhere agnostic of the plugin itself.

However, it doesn't appear that the `trigger` call is either firing or finding the bound event from the other page. None of the console messages show up in Firebug.

Here's my sample plugin (simplified):

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var $canvas,
        context,
        defaults = {
            capStyle: "round",
            lineJoin: "round",
            lineWidth: 5,
            strokeStyle: "black"
        },
        imgElement,
        options,
        pluginName = "myPlugin";

    function MyPlugin(element, opts) {
        this.imgElement = element;
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    $.extend(MyPlugin.prototype, {
        init: function () {
            var $imgElement = $(this.imgElement);
            $canvas = $(document.createElement("canvas")).addClass("myPluginInstances");

            $imgElement.after($canvas);

            context = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");

            $canvas.on("mousedown touchstart", inputStart);
            $canvas.on("mousemove touchmove", inputMove);
            $canvas.on("mouseup touchend", inputEnd);
        }
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (opts) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new MyPlugin(this, opts));
            }
        });
    };

    function inputStart(event) {
        //...processing code
    }

    function inputMove(event) {
         //...processing code
    }

    function inputEnd(event) {
        //...processing code

        // Trigger custom event
        $(this.imgElement).trigger("mydrawevent", [this.toDataURL()]);
    }
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Then from a separate page in the `document.ready` the event is bound:

```
$(".myPluginInstances").myPlugin().on("mydrawevent", function (e, data) {
    console.log("mydrawevent");
    console.log(data);
});
```

From Firebug I am seeing that the `imgElement` does have the listener bound:

```
mydrawevent
    -> function(a)
        -> function(e, data)
```

I've tried quite a few things such as calling the `trigger` on different DOM elements, passing the event parameter data in and out of the array, defining a callback method instead (which had its own issues), and more. I have a feeling the problem is something dumb and right in front of me but I could use more sets of eyes to double check my sanity.

Comment: From a glance it looks like 'this' in inputEnd is referring to inputEnd rather than the plugin - JS is function scoped not block scoped. It appears as though it is accessible without using 'this'. Could you not just try `$(inputElement) ` ?

Comment: Good call, I had tried a whole bunch of varying elements as the trigger but apparently missed the fact that inputEnd was bound to the `canvas` but the event itself was listening on the `img`. In this case, `$(imgElement)` is nothing, `$(this)` is the `canvas` and `$(this).prev()` is the actual `img` that has the event listener bound to it. I knew it had to be something stupid like this. Total brain fart on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As further explanation for my response to Vikk above, the problem was indeed scoping and understanding which objects were bound to what parts of the plugin. In my case, the internal methods that are private event handlers were bound to my `canvas` element but the plugin itself was being instantiated on the `img` element which is at least a temporary requirement of this particular implementation.

Based on this, from the internal event handler the use of `$(this)` meant that it was trying to use `trigger` on my `canvas` element and not the `img` element which had the `mydrawevent` listener attached to it from outside the plugin.